# How to use WITHLOCK from Firebird with Delphi FireDac

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I'm trying to **Block** a table on my system in order to prevent other users from entering the system when the procedure is running, how can I do this using **"WITH LOCK"** with **"FireDac"**? Does this eating lock the table for recording or does it also block for *preview*? And cases block pairing *preview* and *recording* How do you use it? and if not block to *View* which command can I use?
E How to identify via Delphi that the table or registry is locked?

Comment: A `select ... with lock` would be the wrong tool for the job. If you want to lock an entire table, then you should start a transaction with table reservation. See [`SET TRANSACTION`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-transacs-statements.html#fblangref25-transacs-settransac). Doing that in itself is usually already the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Consider if shutting down the database to single connection mode would better serve your purpose. See [gfix manual](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix-dbstartstop.html)

Comment: To lock other applications from the table (...and if all applications work with the same login/password so SQL `revoke` won't do) I'd consider making a specialized `VIEW` that would directly reroute to the table. Before the procedure I would then then change that VIEW body to something like `... as select 1,2,3,4,5 from rdb$database`, blocking everyone's else access to the real table beneath it. Though I agree that the very requirement to exclusive access to the table sounds very weird for concurrent system like Firebird

Comment: That is if the table access is needed. If total "no one can connect the database" is required aim - then surely DB shutdown into SYSDBA-only mode is right what you want

Comment: You might want to try to clarify your question by adding what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: You already asked a very similar question... and we already suggestested you should try to explain what you are trying to achieve. I suppose by "preview" and "recording" you really mean "read" and "write" access. Maybe you should understand better what you are trying to do by reading the firebird documentation at https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-notes-withlock.html

Comment: That said. If you really want to use the WITH LOCK clause, then just do it. FireDAC allows passthrough SQL. If you know the backend is Firebird, what is preventing you from using Firebird specific SQL in your statements? What have you tried? What errors did you get? What did not work? Please provide more details.

Comment: In fact, I have not tried anything yet for the reason that I do not know FireDac very well.